# Fixing overlap between parenthesis and integral limit

Tags: positioning, kerning

I'm using the following snippet widely in one of my articles:

```
\begin{equation}
\left(\int\limits_{U_{s}}f(x)dx\right)^{2}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

As you can see, there's a small overlap that is slightly annoying. Its' presence depends on the limit of the integral, e.g. it disappears if `U_s` is replaced by `U`.

Questions are simple:

1. Is the observed overlap bad from a typographic point of view?
2. How can it be fixed? Adding a space manually works, of course, but there is probably an automatic solution.

Comment: I think many typography nuts prefer to use much smaller parentheses, not to use \left( and \right) but to experiment with ( \big( \Big( \bigg( \Bigg( until it looks just right.

Comment: In general, I would agree with Henri's answer.  But if you wanted to use `\limits`, I would do the manual adjustment in this way, `\left(\int\limits_{~U_{s}}f(x)dx\right)^{2}`, adding a space before the lower limit, because I don't like the default placement of `\limits` on the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer your first question for sure, but I personally find this overlap makes the integral harder to read when it is rendered small.

From a technical point of view, this is a TeX issue with the delimiter height. According to `texdoc impatient`, the height of the parenthesis is computed by TeX using the height of the content and two parameters.

> `\delimiterfactor` gives the minimum ratio of the delimiter
>   size to the vertical size of the subformula, and `\delimitershortfall`
>   gives the maximum by which the height of the delimiter will be reduced
>   from that of the vertical size of the subformula.

The default values of these parameters enforce that the parenthesis is a least `901`/1000 times as high as its content, and that the difference does not exceed `5pt`. You can avoid the overlap by either setting `\delimiterfactor 1000` or `\delimitershortfall 0pt`.

For instance:

```
\def\myeq{\begin{equation}\left({\int\limits_{U_s}f(x)dx}\right)^{2}\end{equation}}
\myeq
\delimitershortfall 0pt
\myeq
```

will render as:

[image: rendering]

Answer (score 4):

How about not using limits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left(\int_{U_{s}}f(x)dx\right)^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Probably the best solution, but I cannot use it: in Russian mathematical typography integral limits should be placed under the integral sign. Though I'll give it a shot in my publications in English, thank you.